# make img tag fill page completelly without creating scroll bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got simple html like below, my goal is to make the image full fill the page completely and proportionally and without the vertical scroll bar.

the image I use https://www.dropbox.com/s/w7t8sj7e5f86s8d/Dior2d1.jpg.zip

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<style type="text/css">
    *{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="mainImg"><img src="my_big_photo.jpg"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should try background images. http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
html, body{
    width:　100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.mainImg{
    width:　100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.mainImg img{
    width:　100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: this full fill the image entire screen. But not proportionally, for that I had to use js to scale the image to the screen size then crop wherever possible

Comment: You don't need JS for that.  The techniques in the CSS tricks should do what you want

Answer (score 1):

[CSS tricks have an article on this.](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)
You want technique number 2.

With your existing HTML, you'll want something like this:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.mainImg {
  position: fixed; 
  top: -50%; 
  left: -50%; 
  width: 200%; 
  height: 200%;
}

.mainImg img {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  margin: auto; 
  min-width: 50%;
  min-height: 50%;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/ekugASE/1/edit

Comment: the image is out of normal proposition with this technique. my image https://www.dropbox.com/s/w7t8sj7e5f86s8d/Dior2d1.jpg.zip

Comment: propostional?  You mean proportions?  It's in proportion, it just centers if the image is wider than the browser

Comment: Can't access dropbox sorry.  What is the width/height of it?

Comment: hi David 3067W x 2048H

Comment: That's big.  What behaviour do you want, given that your image is bigger than most screens?  The technique I used will center the image. http://jsbin.com/ekugASE/3/edit

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you would not load the image in the browser instead of an html page containing the image? Typically when someone wants to cover an entire page with an image it is only used as a background image. If that is the case you could set the background-image for the body in the css/style.

Comment: it's a simple full page image slider that I'm trying to do.

Comment: Ok in that case you may consider taking advantage of Javascript to set styling on the fly. I would make my images display with position:absolute with a very high z-index. Then of course set 100% width or height etc...