# How do I insert an image in HTML so that its fills up the entire screen regardless of screen size?

Tags: html, css

I have inserted an image in my HTML page that looks great on my laptop (because it fills up the entire screen), however when I connect it to my 42" TV screen it doesn't fill up the screen but only a small section of the TV screen. How do I insert the image to make it adapt to every screen size or aspect ratio?

Looking forward to your reply.

Find below my CSS file

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
    #slideshow-container { height:190px; position:relative; }
    #slideshow-container img { position:absolute; left:0; top:0; width:100%; height:100% }
    #slideshow      { position:absolute; left:0; top:0; width:100%; height:100%; list-style:none }
    #slideshow img  { width:120px; height:90px; background-repeat:none; background-position:top left; position:absolute; left:0; top:0 }
    #slideshow      { position:absolute; left:0; top:0; width:100%; height:100%; }
    #slideshow img  { width:1350px; height:660px; background-repeat:none; background-position:top left; position:absolute; left:0; top:0 } 
/* adjust this for your images */
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="slideshow-container">
      <div id="slideshow"> 
          <img src="images/Ads/images1.jpg"> 
          <img src="images/Ads/images2.jpg">
          <img src="images/Ads/images.jpg">
          <img src="images/Ads/images1.jpg">
          <img src="images/Ads/images2.jpg">
      </div> 
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @m59 Yes, I would like the image to fill up the entire screen in sreen in <div id="slideshow">, regardless if one views it from a smart phone , or laptop or even a Smart TV.

Comment: That's some odd code - you use the same selectors multiple times and apply different styles.  Try reading this question from earlier today. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20320452/make-img-tag-fill-page-completelly-without-creating-scroll-bar/20320510#20320510

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're looking for a css solution, this is the way to go:

```
img {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

It uses a unit that is based on the viewport's height `vh`. Just be sure to remove margins, padding, and the space that `inline` elements cause.

Note: `vh` is not supported in older browsers. See http://caniuse.com/#search=vh

There is also the corresponding `vw` for viewport width.

To support browsers where `vh` is not available, you can use javascript to calculate the height and width and update the style accordingly. You would set it up on page load and then keep it updated with an event attached to the resize of the window.

Answer (score 1):

You can set it as a background image and scale it to full size

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/200/200);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2rGMu/)

The same can be achieved with an `img` element, of course

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
}
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2rGMu/1/)

Comment: I believe he is asking how the image, when scrolled into view, can fill the whole height of the screen. This can be assumed as his code sample attempts that behavior.